# Spring oauth2 - Cannot login to /oauth/authorization

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth

I'm trying to secure my REST app with OAUTH2, in this case with Authorization Code Grant. So basically i think that when trying to access the /oauth/authorize endpoint, i should get a login page (from my app) where the user should authenticate with my app in order to make the client app get the token in the redirect_uri. Is this correct?

My clients are in a DB, I have created all the tables Spring Security needs. In this case I have a `client_id = test` and `authorized_grant_types "access_token,refresh_token,implicit,authorization_code"`
This is my AuthorizationServer config

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authManager;

   @Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
    oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
}

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore())
        .authenticationManager(authManager);

    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

}
```

The resource server (in the same app) is

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

     @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http    
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/**").access("hasRole('USER')");

        }

     @Bean
        public TokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
        }

     @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {

            resources.tokenStore(tokenStore());
        }
}
```

Last, my general SecurityConfiguration sets the security levels for the web app part of the application and not for the "/api/**" part. I'm trying with PostMan to send a post request to `http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize` with this parameters: client_id=test redirect_uri=http://test.com response_type=code but i'm getting this error

```
User must be authenticated with Spring Security before authorization can be completed.
```

I thought i should get a login window where the user should authenticate
what i'm doing wrong?